# passing variables as parameters to stored procedures via wpdb from php-script

Tags: wpdb

i am having a slight problem with passing php-variables to a stroed procedure call from a php-script. Here comes the details:

This is how it works very perfect - passing the params as `string`:

```
$myHTML = $wpdb->query( 'CALL show_average_time_spent(2, "2011-10-24", "2011-10-24", @myHTML)' );
```

Brings back a perfect result.

And this is how it not works and throws the error (passing params as variables):

```
$date_from = '2011-10-24';
$date_to = '2011-10-27';
$myHTML = $wpdb->query( 'CALL show_average_time_spent(2, $date_from, $date_to, @myHTML)' );
```

throws this error:

> WordPress database error: [Unknown column '$date_from' in 'field list']
>   CALL show_average_time_spent(2, $date_from, $date_to, @myHTML)

The `$date_from` is only used in this php-script for holding the selected date.

i realy appreciate any kind of help with this issue.

Thanks to all of you trying to help solving this problem.

Cheers,
Joe

Comment: Btw: You should show us the actual procedure and _yes, it's off topic + close vote_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the Codex to see how to [`prepare`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Examples_8) your statement:

```
// Example straight copy-paste from Codex
$metakey    = "Harriet's Adages";
$metavalue  = "WordPress' database interface is like Sunday Morning: Easy.";

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta
        ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value )
        VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )
    ", 
    10, 
    $metakey, 
    $metavalue 
) );
```

Try this with your code too (it's about *security*).

Comment: Hello kaiser, you are my hero. It works fine now with this method. Thanks so much. Have a nice day, Joe. P.S.: if you ever will come to bangkok, i owe you some beers.

Comment: n/p, you're welcome. Could you please hit the check mark below the voting arrows to mark it as solution and close the question? And if I make it to Bangkok, then I'll remind you 'bout that beer :)

Comment: I think it's probably worth noting, though, that the reason that the original query was failing was that you were using single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`). Text within single quotes is not parsed, it is just outputted directly. Text within double quotes is parsed. So what you would have wanted is `'CALL show_average_time_spent(2, '.$date_from.', '.$date_to.', @myHTML)'`. That said, @kaiser's solution is the RIGHT way to do things.